# HTTP request to Azure Active Directory app registration using a managed identity failing with unauthorized error in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

While making the http request to Azure Active Directory app registration in Azure using a "Enterprise application" managed identity, I am getting "unauthorized" error even after assigning the managed identity "application.readwrite.all" permission.

Making GET request to app registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I am using PowerShell to make the request to app registration:

```
$token=<Access token from managed identity>
$headers = @{
    Authorization="Bearer $token"
}

$serviceUri="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$applicationId"

$httpResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $serviceUri -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
```

Can someone help me with what permissions needs to be assigned to managed identity and how we can successfully send a https request to Azure active directory?

I tried PATCH request, GET request after assigning "application.readwrite.all" permission to managed identity.

I tried the "Invoke-WebRequest" with and without the content type.

I tried to query user context as well with uri: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", this also failed with unauthorized error.

Comment: which set of permissions did you configure on the app registration? Delegated or Application? And which scopes do you request when you request a token? As a 3rd tip: paste the token in jwt.ms and check if the scopes etc are correct in the token you're getting.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?force_isolation=true

Comment: App registration has the application.readwrite.all and directory.read.all permission but the managed identity does not have the required permissions to access the details about application.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the access token doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform the action.

**To resolve the error, try the below:**

I created an Azure App service and turned on the system managed identity:

[image]

Now, I assigned the Enterprise Application the `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission like below:

[image]

I generated the access token for managed identity by using below script:

```
$resourceURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/" 
$tokenAuthURI = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=2019-08-01"  
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"X-IDENTITY-HEADER"="$env:IDENTITY_HEADER"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI  
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
```

[image]

Make sure that the `Application.ReadWrite.All` permission is present when you decode the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/):

[image]

I am able to fetch the Application details successfully by using the access token:

```bash
$token=<Access token from managed identity>
$headers = @{
    Authorization="Bearer $token"
}

$serviceUri="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$applicationId"

$httpResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $serviceUri -Method Get -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
```

**Response:**

[image]

```bash
StatusCode : 200  
StatusDescription : OK  
Content : {"@odata.context":"[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#applications","value":[{"id":"d-d2a5-47b2-b7b2-a3af06b9d8ea","deletedDateTime":null,"appId":"2c8cd94f-1fbd-43f]
3-bf74-2699b3838007",...  
RawContent : HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Transfer-Encoding: chunked  
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000  
request-id: 4540ad41-c127-4feea271  
client-request-id: 4540ad41-c127-4fee-90eb-408cd5d71  
x-m...  
Forms : {}  
Headers : {[Transfer-Encoding, chunked], [Strict-Transport-Security, max-age=31536000], [request-id, 4540ad41-c127-4fee-90eb-408cd5d5a271], [client-request-id,  
4540ad41-c127-4fee-90eb-408cd5d5a271]...}  
Images : {}  
InputFields : {}  
Links : {}  
ParsedHtml : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass  
RawContentLength : 8142
```

Comment: That's one way to resolve it. But in my case it's a system assigned managed identity and I don't see the "Identity" menu item. I found out the permission that is required to access an application using token from managed identity, we need to add "Directory Reader" or "Application Administrator" role to the managed identity to get be able to read the application.

Comment: This deosn't solve the issue I had asked the question about. I added the solution in the comments.

Comment: Without assigning the permissions to the managed identity I was able to fetch the details